# Any vs some; if S + any vs if S + some

Tags: compounds

Well, these two words drive me crazy every time I try to chew the cud in order to draw a clear line between them. ANY and SOME. Please consider the following:

1. If you have **any/some** money, please let me know.
2. Do you know **anyone/someone** here?
3. If **anyone/someone** knocks at the door, what will you do?
4. If you talk to **anyone/someone**, stare into their eyes!

Which ones are right, guys? If there is a sentence in which those two are acceptable, please tell me the reason.

Comment: Eye contact is good, staring at someone's eyes is not.

Comment: Maybe because I'm sleep deprived due to the heat, but I don't understand what the S represents in the question title.

Comment: "Do you know anyone here?" = is there any person present whom you recognise?  "Do you know someone here?" = Is there a particular person here who is known to you?

Comment: @Mari-LouA well, it stands for "subject"

Comment: @KateBunting what about "if you have any/some money"?

Comment: Have you looked at the list of related questions on the right? You would say "If you have any X" if you did not know whether the person had any or not.

Comment: Then it should be: If+S+V+any/some. But I never like questions that have a string of letters

Comment: @KateBunting for once the related questions are actually related! Very often I am amazed by how unconnected they are to the OP. The OP could also look at the other questions tagged \some-any\, I suggest filtering them according to votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between "any" and "some" is the implied focus.

With "any", in the first two examples, the focus is on quantity. With "some", the focus is on the object of "some". "Do you know anyone here?" is asking about YOU. The focus is on your knowledge. "Do you know someone here?" focuses the next sentence on that someone.

With examples 3 and 4, the two words are interchangeable. Example 4, as a commenter noted, might be bad advice for many English-speaking social situations.